# Collecting a list of vendors

Tags: c#, dynamics-gp

I have been searching for hours on Google and Microsoft to find a code example of how to collect a list of active vendors from **Microsoft Dynamics Great Plains 9** via **eConnect**.

I have downloaded 3 SDKs, multiple snippets, and an obscene amount of documents, to no avail.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VendorCriteria x = new VendorCriteria();
x.IsActive = new RestrictionOfNullableOfboolean();
x.IsActive.EqualValue =true ;
VendorSummary []=wsDynamicsGP.GetVendorList(x,context);
```